# Como criar um array dinamicamente em PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Eu preciso criar um array no formato:

```
//$arr = ['id' => 1, 'razao_social' => 'Teste'] // saida esperada
// iteração
foreach($prestadores as $prestador){
    // logica separando apenas alguns prestadores
    if ($cont($outro_sql) > 1) {
        $dados = array_add($dados,'id',$prestador->id);
        $dados = array_add($dados,'razao_social',$prestador->razao_social);
    }
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem, porém o resultado do array `dd($dados)` tem como saída o array, mas apenas com o último registro.

Eu preciso que o array seja montado com todos os registros.

Veja, eu sei que o $prestador já é um array, mas eu preciso montar um lógica de acesso ao BD acessando outras tabelas, onde apenas alguns registros irão compor este novo array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro aprender o básico da linguagem antes de fazer qualquer coisa mais complexa.

Aqui você testa uma condição dentro de um *loop*, sendo que ela não vai mudar, então ou vai adicionar tudo, ou não vai adicionar nada:

```
if ($cont($outro_sql) > 1) {
```

Se a condição é fixa, é o caso de testar fora do *loop* em vez de ficar repetindo o teste à toda. Se era para depender do registro corrente, precisa corrigir a lógica. Pode ser que você esteja chamando uma função variável também, aí até faria algum sentido, mas em vista do resto do código sugiro analisar se é isso mesmo que quer. Me parece estranha a construção.

Já neste trecho você está sobreescrevendo continuamente a variável `$dados`:

```
    $dados = array_add($dados,'id',$prestador->id);
    $dados = array_add($dados,'razao_social',$prestador->razao_social);
```

Outra coisa é querer armazenar resultado de `array_add` (seria o caso de `array_push`), que retorna o último valor. Quando se usa `array_push` normalmente não precisa se fazer atribuições.

A não ser, é claro, que você tenha escrito uma função `array_add` que devolva o *array* adicionado nele mesmo, mas aí realmente seria sofrido você determinar como fazer o "par" do `id` e `razao_social` corretos.

Provavelmente (é o que deu pra entender conforme o exemplo no comment do código) seria o caso de fazer algo assim:

```
    $dados[] = array(
      'id' => $prestador->id,
      'razao_social' = $prestador->razao_social
    );
```

Ou isto:

```
    array_push( $dados,
       array( 'id' => $prestador->id, 'razao_social' => $prestador->razao_social )
    );
```

Ou ainda isto, para ilustrar de outra maneira:

```
    $dados = array();

    $par = array();
    $par['id'] = $prestador->id;
    $par['razao_social'] = $prestador->razao_social;

    array_push( $dados, $par );
```

Quando você atribui um valor usando índice vazio (`[]`), o PHP adiciona um elemento ao final do *array*

Sugeriria uma leitura mais aprofundada no manual para compreender os elementos básicos da linguagem, e fazer pequenos exercícios até dominar cada conceito:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/index.php

Comment: Bacco obrigado pela ajuda e conselho. Para constar e li o manual e não estava conseguindo montar a lógica, por isso usei esta ferramenta. Não faria se eu tivesse conseguido. Valeu, funcionou.

Comment: @MarceloGomes dê uma lidinha em especial na parte de arrays, PHP tem várias especificidades. É meio chato ler documentação, mas se for lendo e fazendo pequenos testes avulsos, ajuda a absorver os conceitos. Um problema muito comum é tentar entender a função usando em código mais complexo, confunde. Sempre que precisar dominar um conceito novo, teste ele separado. Crie um script pra teste, e experimente variações nele para observar os efeitos, o manual serve como apoio, mas experimentar o uso é sempre interessante. No seu caso, note que não é um simples array, mas sim um array de outros arrays.

Comment: Note que isto que eu estou recomendando, de testar coisas em separado, eu faço normalmente hoje, mesmo conhecendo PHP faz pelo menos uns 15 anos. Nunca é demais resolver os problemas em separado e juntar na aplicação final. Você acaba isolando bastante os problemas, e fazendo um código naturalmente mais enxuto e organizado ao dividir em partes o problema.

Comment: De qualquer forma, se tiver dúvidas sobre este mesmo assunto, pode deixar comentário aqui que eu complemento a resposta quando puder, e se tiver novas dúvidas, abra novas perguntas. Estamos aqui pra isso. As recomendações são no sentido de você ganhar autonomia, mas sempre que tentar algo e não tiver sucesso, não tenha receio em perguntar.

Comment: Bacco, obrigado por compartilhar sua experiência. Valeu mesmo. Abraços.